# How to get how many rows are inserted in ORACLE?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2

How do I get how many rows are inserted after executing an `INSERT` statement?
I'm using Oracle 11r2 with MyBatis in Java.

Answer (score 1):

You can assign `SQL%ROWCOUNT` to a variable after inserting.